# Eigensystem of a linear interpolation operator. How to explain / interpret?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, spectral-theory, signal-processing

In the case of linear time invariant filtering I know of the famous result that the circulant matrices always have an eigensystem with Fourier basis functions and diagonal matrix given by FFT of first row / column.

But what happens if we interpolate the filter? Can we say anything about the eigensystem then?

I made a small example with the identity filter (leaves vector unchanged). Then the 16x16 matrix interpolating linearly $[0,15] \to [0,14]$ assuming we have sampled at integers $\{0,1,2,\cdots,15\}$ First row : $$\left[\frac {15} {16},\frac 1 {16},0,0,0,\cdots\right]$$ second row:
$$\left[0,\frac{14}{16},\frac{2}{16},0,0,\cdots\right]$$

This gives me the peculiar eigenvalue decomposition:

eigenvectors $[1,1,0,0,0,0]^{(*k)} \cdot [1,-1,1,-1,\cdots]$

Where $(\cdot)^{(*k)}$ denotes convolutional power ( iterated self convolution ). Corresponding eigenvalues seem to be exactly $\frac{16-k}{16}$. Also very curious.

Can we derive or explain this somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by "interpolate the filter"? and what are first and second row? are they the rows of matrix, say $H$ such that $y = Hs$ (where $s$ is input of filter, $y$ its output, and $H$ the matrix of filter coefficients that we get from convolution and that's supposed to be circulant?

Comment: We only consider analyzing the interpolation operation above, the filtering can be done either before or after it.

Comment: @MedNait in that sense it is $y=Hs$ like you say. Say filter matrix for any filter we want to apply is $F$, then $y=FHs$ or $y=HFs$ depending if you want to interpolate before or after applying filter.

Comment: Can't interpolating be considered filtering coupled with zero insertion? Maybe not linear interpolation, but sinc-based interpolation is just an operator to insert zeros between the samples and then another that convolves the result with a low-pass filter.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 : But zero-insertion it is only for integer factor resampling. I want to be able to do fractional resampling, as in our case takes 16 length vector and turns it 15.

Comment: Upsampling and then downsampling (or vice verse) by integer factors will yield any rational change in sample rate. The zero insertion, sample discarding, and filtering are all linear operators and as such can be represented by matrices.

Comment: But sinc resampling is not always the kind of sampling we want to do.

Comment: 1/2: Linear resampling is a linear operator too. Spline interpolation is data-dependent, so it won't work. I guess what I am getting at is that you are interested in the eigen decomposition of an interpolated filtering operator. If the original filtering operator is $\mathbf{A}$, then there is another operator $\mathbf{B}$ that does the interpolation (at least in the sinc-based and linear cases), so that the interpolated filter operator is $\mathbf{BA}$.

Comment: 2/2: If I were tasked with this problem, I'd start by looking at the structure of $\mathbf{B}$ and see if it has some derivable effects on the eigen decomposition of $\mathbf{BX}$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is an arbitrary operator.

Comment: Yeah, no it's not a task, just a curiosity. I don't have so many people give me math tasks these days. I have to come up with them on my own.